# Shortcut/complication to start a specific training on Watch

Tags: apple-watch, shortcuts-app

I'd like to make a shortcut (and then add it as a complication to the Watch) to start, for example, "Outdoor Cycle - open goal". Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a shortcut that starts your desired workout with your desired goal.

   [image]
2. Make sure the shortcut shows on Apple Watch.

   [image]
3. Run the shortcut on your Apple Watch from the Shortcuts app a few times.

   The amount of times you need to run the shortcut for the donation to appear as a complication option depends on how many other shortcuts you run, as only shortcuts considered a priority will be shown.

   Using Siri to run your shortcut may also make it appear sooner.
4. Add the shortcut as a complication on your watch face.

Comment: thanks, it worked! (i had to reboot the Watch in order for the shortcuts to appear as possible complications; also, i disabled "Show on Apple Watch" for the other complications). The only thing is that after clicking on the Cycle complication, Watch asks "Run 'Outdoor Cycle'?" Is it possible to skip this confirmation and just click once?

Comment: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/iwwaf8/apple_watch_always_asks_to_confirm_execution_of/) they say that one has to turn off “Show When Run” but i cannot find this option..